# char array in C++ taking more values than it should

Tags: c++, arrays, char

Hi I am here with very basic question please help me out.
I write a basic C++ code in Borland C++ that is given below now according to rules which I know If **char a[2]** size is 2 it should not take more than 3 character but here in case of this program If I am giving my name as input which is based on 6 characters Hammad it is taking it and shows on screen as I am showing the value store in a;
why it is happening please tell me.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
   char a[2];
   cout<<"Enter your name ";
   cin>>a;
   cout<<"result is"<<a;
   getch();
}
```

Comment: This is undefined behaviour, meaning **anything** can happen. In C++ it is **your** responsibility to avoid making this mistake, the compiler won't tell you.

Comment: 1. A size of 2 bytes only holds 2 characters. That means C++ allocates that much room for your variable, it does not mean that C++ will stop you from putting too much data into it. If you out in extra data, it just overwrites existing memory. Overwriting existing memory is called undefined behaviour, because the outcome is not entirely predictable.

Comment: You simply got lucky that your `cin >> a` did not overwrite anything important. It did overwrite data that it should not have touched, but apparently that data was not critical. What is overwritten is out of your control. And, if I were allowed to supply some input to your program, I would likely be able to take over your computer.

Comment: Actually it's undefined behaviour because the C++ standard doesn't define what will happen if you do it. The result is unpredictable outcome.

Comment: @JacobH an array if 2 char holds only one char and the terminator `'\0'`

Comment: As long as you are using C++, perhaps you should investigate using std::string.  Using it would be very similar, but the memory issue would disappear.